# How to decide number of nodes for CNN model for image classification using tensorflow ? Images are of size 178,218

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, conv-neural-network

How to select the following: Size of filter for convolution, strides, pooling, and densely connected layer

Answer (score 0):

There is no single answer to this question. This [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/MachineLearning/comments/3l5qu7/rules_of_thumb_for_cnn_architectures/) and this [answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/148139/rules-for-selecting-convolutional-neural-network-hyparameters) have some nice discussion. To quote the second post on the Reddit, "Start simple."

Celeba has similar, maybe exactly the same, image size. When I was working with Celeba on a DCGAN project, I gently cropped and then reshaped the images to 64 x 64 x 3. My discriminator was a convolutional neural network and used 4 convolutional layers and one fully connected layer. All conv layers had 5 x 5 window size and stride size of 2 x 2. `SAME` padding and no pooling. The output channels per layer were `128 -> 256 -> 512 -> 1024`. So, the last conv layer output a 4 x 4 x 1024 tensor. My dense layer then had a weight size of classes x 1024. (I had 1 class since its purpose was to determine whether the input image was from the dataset or made by the generator.)

That relatively simple architecture had good results, but it was intentionally built to not overpower the generator. If you're looking for pure classification, you may want a deeper architecture. You might not want to crop as aggressively as I did. Then you can include more conv layers before the fully connected layer. You may want to use a 3 x 3 window size with a stride size of 1 x 1 and use pooling - although I see  architectures abandoning pooling in favor of larger stride size. If your dataset is small, it is prone to overfitting. Having smaller weights helps combat this when dropout isn't enough. That means fewer output channels per layer.

There are a lot of possibilities when choosing an architecture, and there is no hard-and-fast rule for the best architecture. Remember to start simple.